# Synchronizing NTP machines with a high root-time server

Tags: systemd, ntp

I have a small network of machines that use `systemd-timesyncd.service` and need their clocks to be synchronized.  They don't need to be correct, just synchronized.  I have designated one of the machines as an NTP server and the rest of the machines all point to this one, but they take hours to synchronize and when they do, it's terribly inconsistent:

```
Jun 22 18:09:16 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Initial synchronization to time server 10.10.1.30:123 (10.10.1.30).
Jun 22 18:25:50 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 18:34:22 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 18:51:26 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 19:25:34 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 19:59:43 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 20:33:51 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Initial synchronization to time server 10.10.1.30:123 (10.10.1.30).
Jun 22 21:07:59 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 21:42:07 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Server has too large root distance. Disconnecting.
Jun 22 22:16:16 host systemd-timesyncd[10515]: Initial synchronization to time server 10.10.1.30:123 (10.10.1.30).
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit appears to be the "root distance".  This is the latency introduced by the entire route from each client, through the local NTP server, though any other NTP servers, to a "stratum 1" server which has a GNSS reciever or atomic clock.

```
              +---------------------+              +---------------------+
+---------+   |   Stratum 1 server  |  20ms delay  |   Stratum 2 server  |
|GNSS rcvr|---|  Root distance: 0ms +--------------+ Root distance: 20ms |
+---------+   |       nasa.gov      |              |   0.pool.ntp.org    |
              +---------------------+              +----------+----------+
                                                              |
                                                              | 5040ms delay
                                                              |
                                              ==LAN=FIREWALL==+================
                                                              |
           +-----------------------+              +-----------+-----------+
           |      Clients          |   1ms delay  |    Stratum 3 server   |
           | Root distance: 5061ms +--------------+ Root distance: 5060ms |
           |    10.10.1.0/24       |              |      10.10.1.30       |
           +-----------------------+              +-----------------------+
```

Since alignment with the stratum 1 server is less important that alignment with the stratum 3 server, you can increase `RootDistanceMaxSec=` on each client to a more comfortable value.  30 seconds might work.  The default is 5s, so you could be rather close to this number.  Edit `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`:

```
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.
[Time]
NTP=10.10.1.30
#FallbackNTP=
RootDistanceMaxSec=30
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

This will cause the clients to accept `10.10.1.30` as the NTP server, even though it may be far from a stratum 1 server.